# How to select and unselect the data with jquery?

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, jquery

I want to select and unselect the coming data, but in my code this time it just select and the tick image will apear, i want to do when i click again on data the tick will disapperar how can i do that? Thanks in advance

```
    <style>
.highlight{ font-wieght:bold;   color:#F00;}
.amounts{}
.tick{ float:left; margin-top:-5px;}    
.highlight .amount{ display : inline;}
.tick img{  display:none;   width   : 25px; height  : 25px; margin-right: 10px; float   : left;}
.highlight .tick img{   display : block;}
</style>


<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function (){

    jQuery('.amounts').click(function (){
        var pname = jQuery(this).attr('product_name');
        if(!jQuery(this).hasClass('highlight')){
            jQuery('.amount-'+pname).removeClass('highlight');
            jQuery(this).addClass('highlight');
        }

    });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
if(!jQuery(this).hasClass('highlight')){
            jQuery('.amount-'+pname).removeClass('highlight');
            jQuery(this).addClass('highlight');
        }
else {
            jQuery('.amount-'+pname).addClass('highlight');
            jQuery(this).removeClass('highlight');
}
```

Just You can use this.

Comment: My Pleasure to help you sir :D

Comment: Thanks dude, but it didn't work properly, it select next data  :(

Comment: @UsmanAli I already answered you what you asked. But still can you provide me live example? So, I can check what the problem is. That "it select next data" does not explains what problem with the code is.

Answer (score 2):

change:

```
if(!jQuery(this).hasClass('highlight')){
   jQuery('.amount-'+pname).removeClass('highlight');
   jQuery(this).addClass('highlight');
}
```

to

```
jQuery('.amount-'+pname).removeClass('highlight');
jQuery(this).toggleClass('highlight');
```

Answer (score 2):

Well i find the solution

```
 if(!jQuery(this).hasClass('highlight')){
        jQuery('.amount-'+pname).removeClass('highlight');
        jQuery(this).addClass('highlight');
    }
else {
        jQuery(this).removeClass('highlight');
}
```